# Android service on device boot works once

Tags: android, service, background, device, reboot

System tested: Android 6.0 Device Alcatel POP4.
I have a task - run parse function white app is run, suspended, exited and device reboot. 
Issue: when I reboot device the function works only once, and then stops. If I reopen app, then close it, the function will work again in background service. If I reboot device it will be called just once again. No errors given =(
Need help!

```
    public class ParseIntentService extends IntentService {
    MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
    Context context;

    public ParseIntentService() {
        super("ParseIntentService");
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        main.serviceRun(this);
        WakefulBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

}
```

---

```
public class NotificationAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 10000;
    public static final String ACTION = "com.falcode.gratsme";

    public NotificationAlarmReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, ParseIntentService.class);
        context.startService(i);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class BootBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Launch the specified service when this message is received
        Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, ParseIntentService.class);
        startWakefulService(context, startServiceIntent);
    }

}
```

---

```
 public void startAlarm() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationAlarmReceiver.class);
        // Create a PendingIntent to be triggered when the alarm goes off
        final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, NotificationAlarmReceiver.REQUEST_CODE,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        // Setup periodic alarm every 5 seconds
        long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis(); // alarm is set right away
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        // First parameter is the type: ELAPSED_REALTIME, ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, RTC_WAKEUP
        // Interval can be INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, INTERVAL_HOUR, INTERVAL_DAY
        alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstMillis,
                REQUEST_PERIOD, pIntent);
```

### }

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.falcode.sovkombank">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name=".ParseIntentService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".NotificationAlarmReceiver"
            android:process=":remote" />
        <receiver
            android:name=".BootBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you share related code?

Comment: @EfeBudak
Please, have a look, I edited my question